# iOS storyboard: how to handle dynamic, floating content?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard

My App contains a news-section. I'm trying to create a View in my storyboard which will show an news item. A news contains of a title, a date, an image, and some text.

Content like this would be easy to display in HTML since it's content is floating, but as far as I understand iOS elements have a fixed size. I think a `UILabel` could be fine for title and date, `UIImage` for the image and a `UITextView` for the text. I think all elements should be inside a scroll view. The problem is, that the title for some news will fill one line but for other news multiple lines.

How can I handle a setup like this in a storyboard? A link to a guide, tutorial would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways you could approach this.  Ultimately you have control of the size of any of these elements at runtime. From a UX point of view you'd probably want to keep at least some of the elements fixed in size (e.g., the image and the scrollview representing the total size of the news item).  That would leave playing with the relative sizes of the title and the detail.  If you want to show the entire title you can use the `sizeWithFont` method (or one of its variations) of the `NSString` class to calculate how much space to use for the title, and allocate space from the remaining amount to the detail as desired.

UPDATED: I might add that I intended this as a general strategy, not specifically aimed at the new iOS 5 Storyboard functionality.

UPDATED: Well, no tutorial but here are some general guidelines (at least about the way I might tackle it).

I'd set up a `NewsItem` class that encapsulates the elements that you describe here, similar to what I've laid out in the example image.  How you expose `NewsItem` is something of a matter of taste; you might want to start with a UITableView as a container as it would make managing a `NewsItem` collection simpler.  I'd subclass `UITableViewCell` as `NewsItemTableViewCell`, and generate a nominal layout for a `NewsItem` using Interface Builder.  So in the example image, a news item would correspond to one table row.

The main part that you are asking about is identified by the red and blue frames in the image.  Using the above approach, I would add logic in the `NewsItemTableViewCell` to calculate the extent of the title -- this assumes that the View (in this case, the `NewsItemTableViewCell`) has explicit knowledge of the Model (the underlying data for the news item) in the form of a reference (i.e, an instance of a `NewsItem` class
that contains the items you've described retrieved from a web service).  If the width of the title is greater than the default width of the red frame, I'd adjust the height of the red frame (increasing it) at the same time decreasing the height of the blue frame.  This kind of approach avoids having to include extra logic for differing cell heights within the table.

An alternative I often use is to have a Controller class mediate between the View and the Model.  This can be useful when you have a requirement that your table contain different kinds of cells; it also makes tableview cell reuse much simpler. In this case, declare a base class.  This might look something like:

```
@protocol GenericCellController

- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;
@optional
- (void) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;

@end
```

and then:

```
@interface NewsItemTableCellController : NSObject<GenericCellController> {
    NewsItem* newsitem;
}
```

You then set up a collection of table cell controller objects.  This has the advantage that when you implement `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` in your tableview controller code, you only have to delegate to the cell controller object at the appropriate row.  What's more, you can refer to it using a superclass designation; e.g., in a hypothetical `NewsItemTableViewController` class you might have:

```
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) path {
    NSObject<GenericCellController>* cellController = [cellControllerArray objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell* cell = [cellController tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

This approach allows you to have any class derived from NSObject in the collection and polymorphically use delegation to have the derived class handle the rendering logic.  The derived Controller class has its own implementation of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` with a corresponding UITableViewCell-derived subclass as described above.

If you decide to go this way, there are numerous examples of the basics of tableviews and their controllers that you can use as a preface to implementing these ideas.

[image]